# pyhf: Support for Variable Bin Width Histograms

Tags: pyhf

I would like to obtain the expected limits for my analysis using pyhf. The previous iteration of this analysis used variable bin width histograms, and I am wondering whether pyhf can handle this correctly.

I have heard that HistFactory does not support variable bin widths, although I couldn't find any obvious statement of that in the [HistFactory paper](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1456844/files/CERN-OPEN-2012-016.pdf?version=1) (I may be missing something obvious, though). The only dosumentation I could find referring to variable bin widths in HistFactory was on this old [JIRA ticket](https://sft.its.cern.ch/jira/browse/ROOT-4958), along with a related [Root Forum post](https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/binned-ml-fit-with-histfactory/28867).

Naively, I would assume that if HistFactory does not support variable binning, then pyhf wouldn't either. However, pyhf doesn't seem to use the bin edges in any way (at least, they are not passed to pyhf at all). Also, I obtained what looked like reasonable results when running a hypotest on variable-binned distributions.

I couldn't find anything in the pyhf documentation saying not to use variably binned inputs, nor did I find anything in the pyhf GitHub issues or tagged here on Stack Overflow. If one should only use uniformly-binned histograms, then this might be good to add to the documentation somewhere (unless it's indeed already there, and I just completely missed it).

Answer (score 1):

ultimately the likelihood boils down to multiple joint counting experiments where each has its own Poisson term, so really variables bins are not a fundamental issue.

There is a bit of an issue in the RooFit implementation since it doesn't follow the poisson structure directly (rather it uses the RooHistFunc), but in pyhf itt should not be an issue.

PS: we started mygrating Q&A re: pyhf to

https://github.com/scikit-hep/pyhf/discussions/categories/q-a

so feel free to continue the discussion there if you have addiitional questions.

Answer (score 0):

To echo and expand a bit on [Lukas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66291409/8931942), as is seen in the [`pyhf` docs section on `HistFactory`](https://pyhf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/intro.html#histfactory) the main part of the probability model is a product of Poissons over all bins in all channels. From this alone we can see that bin width is not considered in the probability model, and as `pyhf` is an implementation of the full probability model the bin width is not used in `pyhf` as well. This can be further seen in the ["Likelihood Specification" section of the `pyhf` docs](https://pyhf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/likelihood.html) as there is no metadata on bin width to compliment the `data` field.